# Passing an object or parameter with @click

Tags: vuejs3

I created a list of div's where each has a `@click`

```
        <div class="md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10" v-for="c in 4">
            <Course @click="$router.push('/detail')"
                    title="The Course"
                    description="A Course"
                    lessons="1"
                    length="1 hr"
            />
        </div>
```

The `v-for` will be a list of objects, but for now an index is enough. I want to pass an index into the router. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but the `<Course>` is more of less a `div` button that when clicked goes to `/detail`. Which has

```
<template>
    Course Details {{ props.id }}
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps(
    [
        'id',
    ]
)

</script>
```

Comment: I would set the @click event inside the Course component since it is functionality  of the course. Also, I would pass a course object, like `{ id: 1, title: ‘x’, description: ‘y’, lessons: 1, length: 1 }` as a prop to this component.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [router-params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching-with-params). As of now it is not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Course component, that you call from the parent (see CourseList below) and pass in a course object. In the Course component you can handle the click event to [call the router and pass the id as a param](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

Something like this:

**Course component:**

```
<script setup>
  import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
  
  const props = defineProps(['course']);
  const router = useRouter();
  
  const showDetails = () => { 
    router.push({path: '/details', params: {id: props.course.id })
  }
  
</script>

<template>
  <div @click='showDetails' class="course"> 
    Course {{ props.course.title }}
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .course {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
</style>
```

**CourseList component:**

```
<script setup>
  import Course from './Course.vue'

const courses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'one',
    desc: 'First course',
    lessons: 1,
    duration: 1,
  },
   {
    id: 2,
    title: 'two',
    desc: '2nd course',
    lessons: 5,
    duration: 1,
  },
   {
    id: 3,
    title: 'three',
    desc: '3rd course',
    lessons: 4,
    duration: 3,
  },
]  
 
</script>

<template>
  <Course v-for='course in courses' :key="course.id" :course="course">
  </Course>
</template>
```

Comment: This appears to be what I am looking for. I am just trying to confirm it. `<script setup lang="ts">` seems to change some implementation with `router.push`. Thank you for posting.

Comment: Yes, in the composition Api `$router` no longer is available. Script setup is a simpler way of using CA. See https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html  and https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html